# Default python version and pip problem

Tags: python, pip

I have installed Python 3.5.5 on my raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian - jessie) following 2nd answer from [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54365/how-to-download-and-install-python-3-5-in-raspbian?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Python installed.
[EDIT]
  <strike>but the installation folder is located in /home/pi/Python-3.5.5. So, question no.1: Is it a recommended place for it?</strike>
/home/pi/Python-3.5.5 is the remaining folder after installation
<strike>Number 2 is: There seems to be a problem with missing bits in /usr/bin.</strike>
The assumed missing bits are in /usr/local/bin
[/EDIT]

Because there are many python versions, I needed to do
`update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1`

later, i did
`update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.4 2`
so, now after typing

```
update-alternatives --list python
```

I have:

> /usr/bin/python2.7
>   /usr/bin/python3.4

which is fine. When I do:

```
python --version
```

it tells me

> Python 3.4.2

Fantastic, anyway I would like to run Python 3.5 as default, (there is no python3.5 file in /usr/bin) so I did:
[EDIT]

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /home/pi/Python-3.5.5/python 3
```

This was done wrong way: as mentioned earlier /home/pi/Python-3.5.5/ is the remaining folder after installation. Instead, should be:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3.5 3
```

[/EDIT]

now, `python --version`
does what I desired:

> Python 3.5.5

but trying to

```
python -mpip install [something]
```

gives me

> /usr/bin/python: No module named pip

But trying to install python3-pip say:

> python3-pip is already the newest version

And, finally the main question: How to get pip working in current situation?

Comment: Perhaps you should use the command `pip3` rather than `pip`.

Comment: Why are you trying to update Python on a soon-to-be unsupported distro? Stretch includes 3.5.3 (Debian always lags the "latest" to provide a stable tested base) and installing this would be more productive.

Comment: I need to use matplotlib. When try to install it is not happy with anything lower than Python 3.5

Comment: I disagree downloading pip with older python versions. With python 2.7 and alternative installs I found the best solution is... activate the builtin pip : *python -m ensurepip*     Sorry I don't use python3, try and give us a feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of scenario is what the `get-pip.py` script was created for (see [pip.pypa](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing)). Do:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --user
```

(assuming that the `python` is the new symlinked Python 3.5)

What I will say though is that having Python in your home directory like that is probably going to cause some headaches. Did you compile from source? It's much more ideal to use `sudo` to install Python3.5, then use something like `virtualenv` if you're going to require local environments.

**EDIT:** If you're using `make altinstall`, then forget symlinking using `update-alternatives` and just use `python3.5` at the command-line, because other scripts which call `/usr/bin/python` expect Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: First, I wget python3.5.5 from python.org, and compiled (with sudo).

Comment: But you didn't `sudo make install`, otherwise it wouldn't be installed where it is.

Comment: Where is should be installed? Does it matter where I am at the moment of doing 'sudo make install'? (I was in /home/pi/Python-3.5.5)

Comment: It will install under /usr/local/. Have you tried the suggestion in the answer? Does python -m pip work now? And well, you have to call it from the Makefile directory otherwise make won't work :)

Comment: Trying the proposed action from the answer throws an error: "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available"
Anyway: 
I do have a folder python3.5 in /usr/local/lib. There is a missing folder which I can observe in other python folders, which is dist-packages where pip lives...

Comment: This would suggest to me that you didn't build Python with SSL support. Before you built Python from source using the guide you provided, did you `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` ?

Comment: To test, type `import ssl` into the Python interpreter.

Comment: In a better world, installing, using and updating Python wouldn't involve this sort of madness - the hodge-podge of different installers, module names and file locations. It's enough to make you go back to C.

Comment: Python is normally a dream to work with; it's just a shame that [the Raspbian repository](http://archive.raspbian.org/) seems to be lagging behind somewhat, meaning we're having to compile a lot from source.