# Select the default Python to 3.7.2

Tags: raspbian, python, python-3

I had installed Python 3.7 according to the tutorial in this blog post (I changed the Python version to 3.7.2):

*[Building Python 3.6 on Raspberry Pi 3 from sources (clean Debian)](https://bohdan-danishevsky.blogspot.com/2017/01/building-python-360-on-raspberry-pi-3.html)*

However, when I checked my default Python executable with

```
python --version
```

it was still showing the 2.7.13 version

I had tried to set the default version with the following command:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.7'
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

But then when I checked my Python version, it showed an error which cannot found my Python file in the /usr/bin directory.

My Python 3.7 is actually installed in */home/pi*.

Then I tried to change the alias command to this directory, but it failed to set as default as well.

How can I fix this?

I just want to change my default Python interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is inadvisable, and violates the recommendation in [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) to make `python` refer to `python3`.

Doing so (by ANY means) risks breaking your system and any tools which use `python2` are likely to fail.

If you want to use `python3` invoke it with `python3`.

If you want to install Python 3.7.2 in addition to the default Python 3.5.3, by all means use `update-alternatives` BUT change `python3` NOT `python`. The differences between the 2 Python3 versions are small (see https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-7-3-final)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, i think what you say might happening to me because my apps now unable load and showing segmentation fault. but my apps is develop base on Python 3.7 and I already installed the Python 3.7 refer to the blog that i mentioned. May I know what is your advice now?

Comment: I have never installed Python from source, but if you followed normal install procedure it would NOT be in `/home/pi` most probably `/usr/local/bin`. If you undo the update-alternatives and ensure `/usr/local/bin` is on your path (which should be default) it should work.

Comment: Hi, I get what you mean. I just checked with the command sudo update-alternatives --config python
realize all the python should install in /usr/local/bin. 
i tried run my application with python 2.7, it is laggy able to run.
but when i run with python 3.7 using command python3 script.py , it is having segmentation fault still...
any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question *[Default Python version](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82644/default-python-version-and-pip-problem)*, I changed the command to:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3.7 2
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.  Some time ago I tried to install Python 3.7.x, but ended up in a mess, and I needed to create a new SD image card.  I got into trouble because I am a linux newbie and do not know the idea of  "dot/" to find a file .  Another trouble is that I don't know the idea of "aliases" which is filename but could not find the file in that directory, because is virtually linked to somewhere I don' t know how to find.  I did try to study about “alisis" but that is too difficult for newbies.  Eventually I decided to upgrade my python 3.5.3 which comes with stretch and is very stable.

Comment: you are most welcome... i see. i am a newbie now too. lol...
facing another issue when launching my apps, it shows segmentation fault. read another thread say it is file corrupted. omg....

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that the accepted answer above by @Milliways is now out of date:

As of 2019, activating a Python virtual environment (or its functional equivalent) prior to script execution is one way to obtain a consistent cross-platform and cross-distribution experience.

They also state that it is acceptable to point python to python3.